# MERGE with OUTPUT doesn't seem to be doing the right thing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I'm adding a foreign key to a table, and removing any rows that violate the FK, copying them into a ModifiedTable_invalid table. As part of the script, I've got the following MERGE command:

```
MERGE ModifiedTable t1
USING TargetTable tt
ON t1.JoinColumn = tt.JoinColumn
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.FkColumn = tt.FkSource
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO ModifiedTable_invalid;
```

However, this command seems to be inserting EVERY row from ModifiedTable into ModifiedTable_invalid, not just those deleted by the MERGE command. What's going on, and how do I get it to only put the deleted rows in ModifiedTable_invalid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you update a row, it will appear in both the `inserted` (post-update value) and `deleted` (pre-update value) pseudo-tables.  If this seems odd, consider that an update is logically a deletion followed by an insert (though the update may not be physically performed that way).

When used with `MERGE`, the `OUTPUT` clause can [include an extra column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) named `$action`. Adding this column to your query will show which action was taken (`'INSERT'`, `'UPDATE'`, or `'DELETE'`) for each row.

For example:

```
insert into ModifiedTable_invalid(Id /* And other columns */)
select
    Id
    /* And other columns */
from
(
    merge ModifiedTable t1
    using TargetTable t2 on t1.JoinColumn = t2.JoinColumn
    when matched then update set t1.FkColumn = t2.FkSource
    when not matched by source then delete
    output 
        $action as DMLAction,
        deleted.Id as Id /* And other columns... */
) outputs
where
    DMLAction = 'DELETE';
```

Updated rows will have `$action` = `'UPDATE'`.

Also see [Adam Machanic's post on using OUTPUT with the MERGE statement](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx) for some other nice examples.

Comment: This behaviour makes no sense to me. Why would rows that haven't been deleted appear in `DELETED.*`?

Comment: @thecoop - It allows you to access the "before" and "after" values for an update. Conceptually you might consider an update to be a delete followed by an insert even though that often isn't how it actually happens.